# getting started with Stripe on mobile

Tags: stripe-payments

I never thought I would have the situation of too much documentation, but I have at least a dozen browser tabs (including github) open while I try to find the solution to my purchase use case from my mobile app:

user selects from a list of products and quantities. They provide payment information, products and qty and get charged.  Stripe informs our server via webhook the purchase details was successful, so we can fulfill the order.

So far I have completed (following [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?ui=elements) mostly):

1. products created with default and currency in Stripe test dashboard
2. I can take a request from the app and successfully create a paymentIntent via server code.

And here I am stuck - do I submit an invoice, a list of products, or what?  Am I even on the right path here?  Do I need to worry about tax, they are defined as part of the product pricing I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Invoices](https://stripe.com/invoicing) are a separate integration flow in Stripe from [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents). With Payment Intents, you just [specify an amount](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-amount). You [can't use Products and Prices with Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/how-products-and-prices-work#use-products-and-prices). Similarly, Stripe Tax [isn't integrated with Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/tax/set-up#integrate). If you need to use Products/Prices and Stripe Tax, you could use [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout), [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/payments/payment-links), or [Invoices](https://stripe.com/invoicing).

Comment: Thank you, if I want the checkout flow done in the app and not using web redirects, is that possible?  I thought that perhaps the Stripe elements would enable this but those links have success and failure redirect pages, which wouldn't apply to a mobile app.

Comment: If you wanted to use Checkout you could use a custom redirect scheme to redirect to your app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dybG4xmVN3c

Comment: I worked with online Stripe support and they recommended a payment intent so the user stays in the app without redirects.